# Insert into database wihtout client with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, linux, bash

I have a PHP website that parses XML and displays it on a webpage. The XML file changes every so often, therefore changing the webpage. It changes once every 30 minutes.

I want to be able to take the XML data and insert it into my MySQL database. However, I can not find a way to insert the data into the database each time the XML is updated because a client has to be involved and even so the data would be inserted multiple times if the page was visited more than one in that 30 minute time span.

Every time the XML file is updated, I would like my data to as follows:

XML -> PHP -> Database

This might be impossible so I understand I might have to use a separate scripting language to update the database with the phrased XML content. Due to the fact the XML changes have to be trigger the database update PHP may not work in this case. The XML is updated via a short Bash script. I looked into using BASH but it did not seems to do well for parsing XML and updating databases, plus it would be a huge learning curve for me. 
I am running this on an Ubuntu machine.

Any suggestions and help is appreciated.

Comment: how is the xml updated?

Comment: Through nmap. Nmap does not have database capabilities. Just XML

Comment: cron job to check if the file date has changed and then import perhaps. if your relying on the client to visit, just logging its been done or checking file timestamps would stop duplications

Comment: How would I update the database? I would have to do it throrugh another scripting language then. I could even check it with just php and no Cron job but I run into the same error of needing a client to put the data on the database

Comment: just do it with php. xml in to mysql db with php is trivial

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. if no one visits the webpage the data will both be inserted into the database and if 10 people visit the website the same data will be send 10 times. That's why I am having an issue with using php

Comment: log its been inserted, check log before inserting again

Comment: Use the PHP CLI.  You schedule a cron job (or task scheduler for windows) to run the script at whatever frequency you choose.

Comment: That fixes the problem of duplication, but if no one visits the site then the data is not added to the database

Comment: hence the cron job option i mentoned already

Comment: heh, although it could be argued that until someone visits the website, does the data need to be refreshed?  (Nevertheless, cron job / task scheduler is the way to go.)

Comment: I'm not familiar with php CLI. Thanks Smith and Tim, I'll look into using PHP CLI with a Cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to smith and Tim Morton I found a solution.

I created a separate PHP file that would parse the XML into variables and insert the data into the database.

To run the Nmap script that updated the XML file I used a cron job that called a bash script. In the bash script after running Nmap I changed the directory location to the folder that contained my script as well as my XML file. I then ran the PHP file with PHP CLI ( php -f /xxx/xxx/php.php ).

So instead of using a trigger to find out if the XML file changed I updated the database in another PHP file that was called in the same bash script.

IT worked like so:

```
             Cron job > BASH script > Run Nmap       > update XML
                                    > call PHP file  > update database
```

Thanks again, [Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9487972/smith) and [Tim Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129574/tim-morton)